# Game to learn piano play

Tags: music, windows-8, game, educational

I want to start learning piano, but I would like to do this in interactive kinda way.

It would be nice to have some game with some kind of achievements, multiplayer, progress etc. and ability to use a MIDI keyboard as a "gamepad".

Can anyone recommend something like that on Steam (for Windows 8.1)? Does this even exist?  I saw some kind off applications for learning but they have no stats or achievements.

Comment: While these games provide a fun and practical learning platform, you also want to read books and or other publications on the topic to understand other important things.

Comment: @chx101 yeah, I understand that, that's why I want at least something to be fun of it... It is kinda hard to lear piano in the age off 25 when other people learn from 6 years old.

Comment: Yes. I agree. But if you have determination you can do it. All you need to know is rhythm and beats, then the notes, then accents and etc, practice tapping both hands, and the rest you can learn by discovery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Synthesia](http://www.synthesiagame.com/) has most of the features you're looking for:

> start learning piano

It has song from "easiest" to "hardest"

> do this in interactive kinda way

Is "guitar hero" descriptive enough? Just for piano. See screenshot below.

> some kind of achievements, progress

You can earn points and watch your progress. See screenshot below.

> multiplayer etc.

This point is *not* available.

> ability to use a MIDI keyboard as a "gamepad".

[MIDI keyboards](http://www.synthesiagame.com/keyboards/Help/desktop/unknown) are supported

> on Steam?

Not on Steam, but works on Windows 7 SP1 x64 and certainly also above.

The regular price is ~40 USD and it comes with a free version where some of the songs are unlocked.

Screenshots (German, sorry):

[image: Synthesia while playing]

[image: Synthesia Statistics]

Comment: Thanks, I'll stick to this one. It seams to be cheaper and easier ...

Comment: @DmytroTsiniavskyi: did you buy it? There's currently an offer for 29$

Answer (score 2):

[Playground sessions](http://www.playgroundsessions.com/about/software-features) seems to cover your main requirements (achievements, "multiplayer", progress, and MIDI keyboard compatibility). However, it's PC (Windows) or Mac software, and I'm not clear whether that'll be suitable for you...